# Error after setting up Visual Studio to collect all my work from my work's remote server

Tags: parsing, remote-server, parse-error

I have set up the Workspace and have got all folders and can open my project, however, when I open my project I am given an error when I try to run it.

**Parser Error**

An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file apparently.

**Line 1: <%@ Application Codebehind="Global.asax.cs" Inherits="MVCMusicStore.MvcApplication" Language=""C#" %>**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file you are inheriting from (MVCMusicStore.MvcAPplication) most likely wasn't found. At work you don't notice this because it is probably somewhere floating in your SourceSafe or where ever your code is kept. You will need to find that file and copy that over as well.